# How to reload data by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a method to get all the products

```
function listProducts() {
  $.get("./listProducts", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      var $clone = $('#product').clone().removeAttr('id');
      $clone.find('.productName').text(item.nameEn);
      $clone.appendTo('#rowProducts');
    });
 });
};
```

I have another method to add a product, i want when adding a new product, in the success method it does reload to the previous method listProducts() to get the new product list

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
     ......
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "./addProduct",
        data : JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 6000,
        success : function(data) {
         /* **reload listProducts** */
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this?

Comment: Did you try calling your `listProducts()` function where you needed?

Comment: Then just call lisProducts() again? Your data should be in the server already.

Comment: when i do like that it doesn't reload, it displays another time the products list. for exemple i have this list: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 . when i add a new product it displays p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7

Answer (score 2):

Just recall the function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
     ......
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "./addProduct",
        data : JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 6000,
        success : function(data) {
         listProducts();//just recall the function here
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: when i do like that it doesn't reload, it displays another time the products list. for exemple i have this list: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 . when i add a new product it displays p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7

Comment: is it possible to clear it out before reloading or do you need it to modify what is in place?

Answer (score 1):

use [window.location.replace("your lising product url");](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

on the successful call of ajax function.

I modified your jquery below . hope this will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
     ......
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "./addProduct",
        data : JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 6000,
        success : function(data) {
         /* **reload listProducts** */
            window.location.replace("your lising product url");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validProduct').on("click", function(e) {
    ......
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "./addProduct",
      data: JSON.stringify(product),
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 6000,
      success: function(data) {
        //recall this function
        listProducts();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: when i do like that it doesn't reload, it displays another time the products list. for exemple i have this list:
p1 p2 p3 p4 
p5 p6

.     when i add a new product it displays 
p1 p2 p3 p4 
p5 p6 p1 p2 
p3 p4 p5 p6 
p7